# Узнать откуда пришел пользователь js

Tags: javascript

Как узнать откуда пришел юзер?

Пример: Человек вводит в гугле фразу, ему выбивается результат поиска. Юзверь переходит на сайт по ссылке из гугла. Вот как мне узнать откуда он пришел на сайте при помощи js? Именно на js.

Или же юзер перешел с рекламы и т.д.

Answer (score 7):

Попробуйте так:

```js
var referrer_url = document.referrer;
console.log(referrer_url); // вот ваша строка
```

Comment: Полную ссылку никак не получить?

Comment: @Tsyklop, что значит полную ссылку?

Comment: @Tsyklop полностью согласен с Grundy, `document.referrer;` возвращает полную ссылку с указанием протокола передачи (http, https), покажите что вам вернул результат, попробуем разобраться.

Comment: @RifmaMan, подозреваю автор вопроса хочет узнать по какой именно рекламе был клик, например. Очень похоже на сбор статистики каким-нибудь google analytics

Comment: @RifmaMan это не полная ссылка. Если заметите то когда вы в гугле у этой странице url очень длинный, а мне приходит только домен считай.

Comment: @Grundy не по рекламе, а полный url с той страницы с которой пришел юзер. В поиске гугл url длинный, а я получаю только домен по сути.

Comment: @Tsyklop, потому что гугл сам делает редирект и устанавливает все свойства как хочет. Поэтому в общем случае то что ты хочешь - невозможно. Плюс служебный урл гугла тебе не должен быть важен, гугл его делает для сбора своей статистики, и тебе отдает что он действительно пришел через гугл, а не что-то еще.

Comment: @Tsyklop я точно не знаю механизм размещения рекламы, но кажется я вас понял, предположу, что, ссылка выглядит длиннее, по клику происходит редирект на сайт рекламы а уже от туда на ваш сайт и по этому вы видите не то что хотелось бы, в этом случае вам стоит почитать api сервиса где вы размещали рекламу или же обратиться к ним в тех.поддержку